# Select data where column from table is different from column from another table

Tags: sql

I need to select data from a table (table1) where a specific column is different from another column from another table(table2)

Something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.column1 != table2.column2
```

---

I do the change like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table1
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table1.column1 != table2.column2
```

I have a table(table1) that I store some people.I need to select random, one by one and add to another table(table2).If a person it's added ,that person can be selected one more time until all the people are selected . This is my query :

```
SELECT * FROM people inner join people_generated on people.id = people_generated.id WHERE people.id != people_generated.id_people ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

This return a empty result : "MySQL returned an empty result set"

The second table "people_genrated" is empty so,remain people to generate.Why result is empty?

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like this,

```
SELECT t1.name FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM table1
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table1.column1 != table2.column2
```

Comment: Can you explain why you use `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, join changed to inner, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
 Select rooms.single from rooms where rooms.single<>checkin.room_no;
```